# Google Play Games not working o some of our app languages

Tags: android, google-play-games

So we integrated the Google Play Games on our app for achievements and leaderboards, it works fine when using iOS and when we run our app on Android devices using portuguese language. When trying other languages (US-English, French) we get 403 errors:

```
E/Volley  ( 4224): [405] a.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=en_US
E/SignInIntentService( 4224): Access Not Configured. The API (Google Play Game Services API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
```

The app seems configured in the play console, and as a said, works fine when the API call is to https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=pt_BR